# How can I delete column names in heatmap.2 in R?

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I've built a great heatmap.2 in R but I am trying to remove the column names at the bottom of the heatmap because they are illegible. I am not able to delete the column names.

I've tried doing labCol = NULL and nothing seems to happen. Additionally, colCol = "white" also doesn't work. Any suggestions?

````
data<-read.csv("Symptoms Only.csv",row.names=1)

data$Subject_type<-gsub("0","Contact",data$Subject_type)
data$Subject_type<-gsub("1","Survivor",data$Subject_type)
data$Gender<-gsub("0","Male",data$Gender)
data$Gender<-gsub("1","Female",data$Gender)

condition_colors <- unlist(lapply(data$Subject_type,function(x){
  if(grepl('Contact',x)) '#FFC0CB'
  else if(grepl('Survivor',x)) '#808080'
  }))

condition_colors

colnames(data)
data<-data[-c(1:3)]
colnames(data)
data<-t(data)

data<-as.matrix(data)

x<-data

z <- heat.clust(x,
                scaledim="column",
                zlim=c(-3,3),
                zlim_select = c("dend","outdata"),
                reorder=c("column","row"),
                distfun  = function(x) as.dist(1-cor(t(x))), 
                hclustfun= function(x) hclust(x, method="ward.D"),
                scalefun = scale)

heatmap.2(z$data,
          Rowv=z$Rowv,
          Colv=z$Colv,
          trace="none",
          scale="none",
          symbreaks = TRUE,
          srtCol=90,
          adjCol=c(0.8,1),
          key=FALSE,
          dendrogram = "both",
          lhei=c(1,5),
          cexRow = 1.1,
          margins=c(4,7),
          labCol = NULL,
          xlab="complete",
          ColSideColors = condition_colors,
          col=rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu"))(256)),
)```
````

Comment: you can try to set colnames to empty string "" .  so in your case, try mat = z$data ;  colnames(mat) = rep("",ncol(mat)) ; heatmap.2(mat, Rowv=z$Rowv,Colv=z$Colv, ... )

Comment: Genius. That worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: you're welcome! Have fun plotting!

Comment: Oh yeah, I will post an answer below with an example, in case anyone is interested in it. Hard to follow comments sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

The image is base R plot, so setting xaxt="n" will remove column names. You would set the column names to empty strings, but maybe not so advisable.

```
library(gplots)
data(mtcars)
# correct solution
heatmap.2(x,xaxt="n")
# not so good
colnames(x) = rep("",ncol(x))
heatmap.2(x)
```